# change value of dropdownlist in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a dropdown in ASP.NET web form but I can't change the value of this 
my dropdown :

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="dropeditdeactive" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem Value="false">Active</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="true">Deactive</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

and my code to change it :

```
protected void DropSiteId_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      //lblError.Text = DropSiteId.SelectedValue.ToString();
      ConnectionManager cm = new ConnectionManager();
      cm.Command.CommandText = "Mysp_tblSitesRead";
      cm.Command.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.SmallInt).Value = int.Parse(DropSiteId.SelectedValue.ToString());
      cm.Command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
      cm.Connection.Open();
      SqlDataReader dr = cm.Command.ExecuteReader();
      while (dr.Read()) { 
      dropeditdeactive.SelectedValue = (dr["URL"]).ToString();
      }
      cm.Connection.Close();
  }
```

when I set break point on `cm.Connection.Close();` and read data of  `(dr["URL"]).ToString();` in immediate window I get this error :

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Data.dll
>   Additional information: Invalid attempt to read when no data is present.

even I can't set `Value` with this code :

```
dropeditdeactive.SelectedValue = "false";
```

or using `Convert.ToBoolean` !!

Comment: Check the value of dr.HasRows right before you read the values. Is that true or false. Also, are you positive that your stored procedure is returning a column labeled "URL"?

Comment: what is the result of dr["URL"] ? is it true/false or what ?

Comment: @macoms01 result of it is true

Comment: @NiMa ist boolan in database

Comment: What is the value of dr.GetValue(dr.GetOrdinal("URL")) right before you read the URL in your code (right before you execute this line: dropeditdeactive.SelectedValue = (dr["URL"]).ToString();?)

Comment: @macoms01 before read : 2 and after : The expression cannot be evaluated while in run mode.

Comment: so you want to set value "2" to "dropdown.selectedValue" ? but you can only set "true" or "false"

Comment: But in database just i have 0 and 1 !!!

Comment: what is the type of URL Field in the db?

Answer (score 0):

Check if the reader has data. ie:

```
if(dr.HasRows)
{
   // code goes here
}
```